# How to incorporate updates to windows 8.1 installation media?

Tags: windows-8.1, updates, bootable-media

I must do a fresh Windows installation. I have access to a legal copy of windows 8.1 on a older laptop that runs windows 7 and a 8GB USB. How can I include all current available updates to my future Windows 8.1 USB?

Comment: You use the DISM tool to extract the component store then use that to create a new installation media.  There are tools of course that do this for you.  The entire process is well documented, I suggest the tools, because doing it by hand is documented but not exactly simple.  I would just use the Windows 8.1 Update 1 installation media and be done with it personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, you can download all the post Windows 8.1 Update 1 updates (.msu files) then extract the .cab of each .msu (7-zip can do the trick or the following command `wusa KBxxxx.msu /extract:C:\Temp\w81updates`) into lets say C:\Temp\w81updates folder.

Then you can inject these updates to you USB installation media with the Microsoft dism tool.

1. Mount the installation image

`dism /mount-wim /wimfile:"F:\sources\install.wim" /index:1 /mountdir:C:\Temp\mount`

2. Inject updates

`dism /image:C:\Temp\mount /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Temp\w81updates"`

3. Commit changes

`dism /unmount-wim /mountdir:C:\Temp\mount /commit`

But honestly you should use Windows Update after installing Windows 8.1, it will be less painful.